# maximal Cohen-Macaulay module

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

This is from CM Rings (Bruns & Herzog) p 64 2.1.20. Show that a one dimensional Noetherian local ring has a maximal Cohen Maucaulay module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $R/\mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$.

Comment: In this case R/p has dimension 1, but why it has depth 1? R is not necessarily CM, so R can have depth 0.

Comment: $R/p$ is a domain, so has depth 1, both as a ring itself and as a module over the original ring.